# How to easily switch off Toastr JS

Tags: toastr

What is the easiest way to switch on and off Toastr JS ? I did not find a solution in the docs.  My project is an angulat one, I am using Toastr for my dev environnement and want toasts to stop displaying when building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add a CSS rule-set. You can just use the target option:

```
// turn off
toastr.options.target = null

// turn on
toastr.options.target = 'body'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer is via css of course.

```
#toast-container {
   display:none;
}
```